# What do I check when Vim digraphs are not working

Tags: vim

What can I do to make my vim digraphs work?

In insert mode, I type in

> ctr-k a'

and I get an underscore.

> :help digraph-table

gives a table with the first 160 chars in the first column. The rest of the chars are underscores.

> ^@
>
> ^A
>
> ^B
>
> ^C...
>
> ~Z
>
> ~[
>
> ~\
>
> ~]
>
> ~^
>
> ~_
>
> |
>
> _
>
> _
>
> _ ...

In command mode, I've done

> :set encoding=utf-8

doesn't make a difference.

:digraph gives a table, which also has underscores after 160.

> NU ^@ 10 SH ^A 1 SX ^B ...
>
> AC <9f> 159 NS _ 160 !I _ 161 Ct _ 162 Pd _
>   163

My main question is this: What can I do to fix digraph in vim?
If that question can't be answered, then do other people have underscores after 160 in their digraph tables?

Edit:
Looks like tmux doesn't support characters other than utf-8 since about 2016.

Comment: After typing `Ctrl-K a'`, when you leave insert mode, move the cursor over the underscore you just inserted and type `ga`, what output do you get?

Comment: <_> 225, Hex 00e1, Octal 341

Comment: That's the right character. So the only problem is that it's rendered wrong. How are you running vim? In some terminal emulator?

Comment: in tmux. But I've tried it in the normal mac terminal, and I get question marks instead of underscores.

Comment: In normal mac terminal I get <?> <|a> <M-a> 225, Hex e1, Octal 341 . About the same as in tmux.

Comment: What do you get when you run `perl -wE 'binmode STDOUT; say "\xE1"'` in your terminal (outside of tmux)?

Comment: I get a question mark, '?'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197231/discussion-between-melpomene-and-flobacca).

Comment: What does the `locale`command say? What about `env | grep ^LC_`? If you go to Terminal.app preferences, look at the current profile, "Advanced" tab... is "Text Encoding" set to "Unicode (UTF-8)"?

Comment: on mac computer, on tmux, locale results in LANG="en_US" all the LC_XXX="en_US"

Comment: on mac computer, on tmux, env | grep ^LC_ results in  LC_ALL=en_US and LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe tmux stopped supporting characters other than utf-8 around 2016. So tmux does put the symbols in the text, but shows them as underscores.

On my mac terminal, but outside of tmux when in vim if I :set encoding=utf-8  then digraphs work and the symbols show.

On my mac, inside of tmux in vim when I :set encoding=utf-8, then the digraphs work, but the symbols are not shown in the window. In insert mode I type ctrl-k a ', then leave insert mode, move the cursor over the underscore and type ga, then the output is <_> 255, Hex 00e1, Octal 341. So the symbol is there, but is shown as an underscore in tmux. I'm using this on an .html file, and the symbol does show correctly in the browser.

I'm thinking that TMUX just doesn't show the symbols, but they are there.